# how to match two tables with php and sql code?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables: one for student and one for trades , i need to make a query to match the id with id_student in trades table kowing that id_student is foreign key to student table which has the id column as a primary key. i get nothing from the following code in the trades controller.

```
$trades = new trades();
    $trades = students::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('id_student', '=', auth()->id_student())
    ->with(['trades'])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `auth()->user()->id_student` not `auth()->id_student()` :

```
$trades = Students::orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->where('id_student', auth()->user()->id_student)
    ->with(['trades'])
    ->first();
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work .. :(

Comment: Explain in more detail about "didn't work"

Comment: i can't get trades ordered by student id according to the id column in student table

Comment: Is there an error or something that you think is not working?

Comment: the problem is there is no error ... it gives nothing actually

Comment: Looks like it's your data problem. I just revised your code error.

Comment: could you explain more please?

Comment: $trades = students::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
  $trades->trades()->where('id_student', auth()->user()->id)->first();

OR

$trades = Students::orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->where('id_student', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with(['trades'])
    ->first();